SONARQUBE 9.9.7 : C# Windows Form : Analisar apenas um arquivo .CS
Tem uma solução em C# Windows Forms. Mas desejo apenas analisar um arquivo apartado, separadamente (.CS).
Motivo : Projeto Legado e muito Grande. Por isso preciso analisar apenas um .CS
Como devo proceder ?
+Grato!

Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.
